# Word that means not being upfront about your intentions in the beginning of your stated goals

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that means not being upfront about your intentions in the beginning of your **stated** goals. Emphasis on the word stated, a goal has to be explicitly stated.

It should be an adjective. Below are example sentences.

> Richard Nixon passed laws and policies against drugs, but he was _____ in his public appearances, as he failed to disclose he wanted to target the anti-war hippies against the Vietnam war and also black people.

> Theresa May claimed that the Investigative Powers Act would prevent and tackle serious crime and organized crime, but she was being ____ as the amount of government departments with access to data was excessive and people could be subpoenaed without there being suspicion of a crime.

> In Kyle's attempts to seduce Kathy to be his girlfriend, he decided to be ______ in his seduction attempts by going to the after school computer club and playing multiplayer flash games with her on a pally level.

The words disingenuous, secretive and deceitful isn't suitable.

Secretive isn't suitable because to use it in the example sentences above, it would imply that the person (or speaker) already had a preconceived intention that they kept a secret while implementing new plans, when it's more likely that someone other than them who would change the spirit of the law, procedure or rules. Deceitful isn't suitable because to gain something from deception, whether financial or not, it is fraud, and no fraud is going on. Disingenous is too broad a word with too much scope than my desired word is for, also it's not about pretending to know less than you actually do, but instead doing more in future then you say you're going to do.

Comment: Devious or sneaky, for two. As a side note, all 3 sentences are less than intelligent, regardless of the adjective.

Comment: *circumspect* is a possibility. But the question is a troll, is it not? And thus an example of the phenomenon itself.

Comment: Please elaborate on ***why*** those words aren’t suitable.  Otherwise you may get equally unsuitable words as answers.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: 'Disingenuous' has appeared in various duplicate threads.

Answer (score 0):

[Reserved](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reserved) - tending to keep your feelings or thoughts private rather than showing them.

[Reticent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reticent) - unwilling to speak about your thoughts or feelings.

[Tight-lipped](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tight-lipped) - refusing to say very much about something.

[Cagey](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cagey) - unwilling to give information.

[Taciturn](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/taciturn) - tending not to speak much.

Comment: You should include dictionary definitions/links for each of your chosen words.

Comment: You should include dictionary definitions/links for each of your chosen words. [Answers should be complete in themselves here, not elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/)

Comment: The answer would be stronger for elaborating on *cagey*, for its deceptiveness, and dropping all others.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I've already included dictionary links for each of the words. Why ask for it again? Not sure what the downvotes are about, since a question like this doesn't warrant an answer any deeper than what I've provided.

Comment: Actually it does warrant that. Read the MSE question and answer I linked to. Answers need to be **complete in themselves,** quoting what is necessary to support your choice of word and linking to the quotation as required by the citation rules. Yes, rules. There are standards set for answers, and I'm afraid this doesn't meet them.

Comment: What part of "I've already included dictionary links for each of the words" doesn't make sense to you? Someone said, "Include links!" I've included links. You then proceed to say, "Include links!" In what world does that make sense?

Comment: Please read the network article I linked to. Perhaps I should have written "definitions **and** links", but the article explains.

Comment: Links also need attributing. If a quote is from the Tiimes say, one needs to state that fact. Otherwise, one could be sued for breach of copyright.

Comment: @AndrewLeach / means or. Yes, you should've said that.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if you hover over the link it says dictionary.cambridge.org. That is attributing. Even if it didn't, getting sued for something like this is extremely improbable, to say the least. For one, it has never happened in the past to any of the se (or other forum) users, and if it were to happen, it would be all over the news. It seems like some people on stackexchange like to criticize for the sake of criticism.

Comment: If I  hover over the link it says nothing.

Comment: It doesn't show you the target url in the bottom-left corner? Pretty sure that's the standard in browsers. Certainly the case in Chrome and Firefox.